# CentoOS - iptables issue when trying to enable specific IP

Tags: centos, iptables

I've got the following iptables:

```
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
3    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22 
4    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 
5    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:443 
6    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8080 
7    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8090 
8    ACCEPT     tcp  --  1.2.3.4              0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3306 state
```

NEW,ESTABLISHED

Can anybody answer me why my 3306 port is still closed for ip 1.2.3.4? What am I missing?

Comment: Is this `INPUT`, `FORWARD`, or `OUTPUT` chain assuming filter table? Also, show the default policy for your chains and the error message you get when you try to connect.

Comment: Is the MySQL process running and configured to listen to external requests? By default, MySQL is configured to only listen for UNIX socket connections, not network connections.

Comment: @Khaled this is INPUT. And the MySQL is configured to listen to external requests.

Comment: Is the state NEW? What is the creation command? Run ipables-save to see

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment but submitting it as an answer because it's too long.

**First:** How are you confirming that it's closed? Are you trying to connect from the outside? What response are you getting and what is the expected response?

**Second:** Can you show the complete `iptables -L -n`? Want to see the complete filter table including policies.

**Finally:** did you confirm that the port is being listened to on your machine? Using something like `netstat -lpn | grep 3306` would confirm that. Make sure it's listening on the IP you're trying to hit (i.e., if it's only listening to `localhost`, then it won't respond to another IP).